# Is there Any API for getting the Trash(Recycle bin) items in one drive graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'd like to get the list of deleted files for a user. Is there any API for getting deleted items in the graph API?

Comment: This is currently not supported: See https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/424

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thanks

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I have tried delta API to get the deleted items, I can able to get the id's of deleted items, But when sending a GET([driveitem.get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get)) request to the graph for (/me/drive/items/{item-id}) the deleted items I am getting **404**, Can You please help me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: It isn't possible to retrieve (or restore) a deleted item. They are surfaced as part of the delta so systems syncing are aware they need to remove it but that is the only data provided at this time.