# Graph API: Is there any way to download items in OneDrive Recycle bin?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I am not able to find any way to download items in OneDrive Recycle bin using Graph APIs. Is this functionality supported? Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this.

Have gone through following old threads which say this is not supported. Wanted to know if anyone has tried this recently and/or found any workaround for this.

[Is there Any API for getting the Trash(Recycle bin) items in one drive graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275778/is-there-any-api-for-getting-the-trashrecycle-bin-items-in-one-drive-graph-api)

[Is there any way to fetch the recycle bin items of share point office365 using graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64658030/is-there-any-way-to-fetch-the-recycle-bin-items-of-share-point-office365-using-g)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OneDrive Personal then a workaround can be to restore the drive item, download it and delete it again. It requires to know the drive item id.

[Restore drive item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-restore?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)